# Basic Calculator Help Java

Tags: java, project, calculator

I am trying to create a calculator for my school project, but for some reason when i try to compile, it says I have a problem and I have no clue how to fix it. I am getting the error "Multiple markers at this line
    - The local variable inputA may not have been 
     initialized
    - The local variable inputB may not have been 
     initialized" at this part:

```
     atimesb = (inputA * inputB);
     adividedbyb = (inputA / inputB);
     aplusb = (inputA + inputB);
     aminusb = (inputA - inputB);
```

is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int inputA;
         int inputB;
         int atimesb;
         int adividedbyb;
         int aplusb;
         int aminusb;
         atimesb = (inputA * inputB);
         adividedbyb = (inputA / inputB);
         aplusb = (inputA + inputB);
         aminusb = (inputA - inputB);

         String operation;

         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  

         System.out.println("Enter the first number");  
         inputA = in.nextInt();  

         System.out.println("Enter the operation"); 
         operation = in.next();

         System.out.println("Enter the second number");  
         inputB = in.nextInt();  



         if (operation.equals ("+"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " + " + inputB + "=" + aplusb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("-"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " - " + inputB + "=" + aminusb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("/"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " / " + inputB + "=" + adividedbyb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("*"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " * " + inputB + "=" + atimesb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("add"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " * " + inputB + "=" + aplusb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("subtract"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " - " + inputB + "=" + aminusb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("divide"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " / " + inputB + "=" + adividedbyb);
         }
         if (operation.equals ("multiply"))
         {
             System.out.println(inputA + " * " + inputB + "=" + atimesb);
         }


}
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Please include the full error that you're getting, as it'll help others to assist you. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add more details on the error you are facing. Copy and paste the error trace here.

Comment: When you divide numbers be careful, remember that dividing two integers (unlike multiplying them, adding or subtracting) that you will end up with non integers (potentially) so should store your result as a float.

Comment: I am getting the error                                                                                   "Multiple markers at this line
 - The local variable inputA may not have been 
  initialized
 - The local variable inputB may not have been 
  initialized"

Comment: The error is exactly as it says: You haven't initialized (read in) inputA, inputB. You have to do so before using them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what it means to initialize a variable, could someone please explain it to me? Or tell me how to do it. After all, I have only been coding for 3 months

Comment: It’s an aside, but a tip worth passing on: use camel-case variable names `aTimesB`, `aDividedByB`, etc. `adividedbyb` is harder to read for someone who didn’t write it (and will be for yourself too if you revisit your code in 3 months from now).

Answer (score 2):

You need to read in the values before using them.
Like this:

```
     System.out.println("Enter the first number");  
     inputA = in.nextInt();  

     System.out.println("Enter the operation"); 
     operation = in.next();

     System.out.println("Enter the second number");  
     inputB = in.nextInt();  

     atimesb = (inputA * inputB);
     adividedbyb = (inputA / inputB);
     aplusb = (inputA + inputB);
     aminusb = (inputA - inputB);
```

Comment: Welcome. I hope now you understand why it wasn't working.